# Regular expression (preg_match) in PHP

Tags: regex, preg-match

Just simple question (I've google this but not found the answer). What's the meaning of **?P**
in this statement :

```
preg_match('/^posts\/(?P<id>\d+)$/', $url, $matches);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(?P<name>patt)` is a [named subpattern](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.subpatterns.php). It means that you can access the match for that subpattern by looking in `$matches['id']` as well as the usual `$matches[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

It captures the match of id into the backreference "<name>" which is <id> in this case.
Check this link for more clearification: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php